# Doctrine 2 + Zend Framework 2 creating nested forms from annotations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to rapidly create an admin panel for my application which uses Doctrine 2 and Zend framwork 2. I am using Zend framework's form annotations to create forms from my entities. This works perfectly for simple entities and for entities with a ManyToX relationship (using DoctrineModule Object Select/Checkbox Elements), however I have been unable to figure out the correct annotations to put on a field to create a nested form.

Simple example a user has a current address and multiple previous addresses

```
class User
{
  /*
   * Doctrine annotations for One to One 
   */
  protected $address;
  /*
   * Doctrine annotations for One to Many
   */
  protected $previousAddresses;
}


class Address 
{
   /*
    * doctrine annotations
    * form annotations
    */
   protected $street;

   ...etc
}
```

Without creating a new form/fieldset instance for each entity how can I compose the two forms allowing an admin user to edit a user and all their addresses in the same form (or for that matter add aditional addresses and create users from scratch)

Essentially what I need to know is the correct combination of annotations to put on each of the address fields; any additional annotations for the address entity (I suspect a doctrine hydrator somewhere in the mix), any service locator config and additional classes needed.

I know it can be done using a custom fieldset class however I'm looking for a solution that uses the form annotations from the address entity and any other entities I may attach later.